# How to improve node decoration of a solution tree?

Tags: critique, graph, graphviz

I am making a [solution tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Issue_tree). The basic rule of it is to consistently answer the "how" question. For example, to achieve "Goal" I need to achieve "Goal 2" (or "Sub goal") . But I add other node types into the basic solution tree: `Better goal`, `Supporting goal`, `Example`, and `Action`. I want the viewers to be able to distinguish them effectively.

Here is my current design:

[image]

My idea is that if the node is a regular goal, then it's better to have it dull, and have other types be more attractive. `Action` nodes are in red because they should attract more attention, also they are the closing nodes. `Example` nodes are in plain because they are least important. I also use dashed arrow to further emphasize this.

However, for `Better goal` and `Supporting goal`, I don't know to decorate them. I guess `Better goal` should stand out of regular goals, but I'm not sure if `Supporting goal` should stand out as well or not. With the current design I still find hard to distinguish them. Do you have any suggestion?

I use Graphviz to generate the graph. It provides quite a lot of [node shapes](https://graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html) and [arrow shapes](https://graphviz.org/doc/info/arrows.html) to choose. I can even use [basic HTML on lables](https://graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#html). I have thought about using emoji in the label, but I wonder whether we can only do this with node decoration or not. Graphviz also accepts using custom SVG images for nodes, but I haven't tried that yet.

Here is the code:

```c
digraph test{
fontname="Lato";

node [ shape=plaintext style="filled, rounded" fontname="Lato" margin=0.2 fillcolor="#c6cac3" ]
Goal -> "Goal 2" 

node [ shape=box, penwidth=1.5 fillcolor="#D1E4DD" ]
Goal -> "Better goal"

node [ shape=note fillcolor="#D1D1E4" ]
"Goal 2" -> "Supporting goal"

node [ shape=plain fillcolor=white ]
"Better goal" -> "Example" [ style=dashed]

node [ fillcolor="#E4D1D1" shape=polygon ]
Goal -> "Action"
"Better goal" ->"Action 2" 
"Supporting goal" -> "Action 3" 
}
```

[Try it online](http://magjac.com/graphviz-visual-editor/?dot=digraph%20test%7B%0Afontname%3D%22Lato%22%3B%0A%0Anode%20%5B%20shape%3Dplaintext%20style%3D%22filled%2C%20rounded%22%20fontname%3D%22Lato%22%20margin%3D0.2%20fillcolor%3D%22%23c6cac3%22%20%5D%0AGoal%20-%3E%20%22Goal%202%22%20%0A%0Anode%20%5B%20shape%3Dbox%2C%20penwidth%3D1.5%20fillcolor%3D%22%23D1E4DD%22%20%5D%0AGoal%20-%3E%20%22Better%20goal%22%0A%0Anode%20%5B%20shape%3Dnote%20fillcolor%3D%22%23D1D1E4%22%20%5D%0A%22Goal%202%22%20-%3E%20%22Supporting%20goal%22%0A%0Anode%20%5B%20shape%3Dplain%20fillcolor%3Dwhite%20%5D%0A%22Better%20goal%22%20-%3E%20%22Example%22%20%5B%20style%3Ddashed%5D%0A%0Anode%20%5B%20fillcolor%3D%22%23E4D1D1%22%20shape%3Dpolygon%20%5D%0AGoal%20-%3E%20%22Action%22%0A%22Better%20goal%22%20-%3E%22Action%202%22%20%0A%22Supporting%20goal%22%20-%3E%20%22Action%203%22%20%0A%7D)

Comment: I think your foal is too opaque

Comment: @joojaa, you like your equines semi-transparent?

Comment: Shouldn't the arrows point the other way? I mean you end up at the goal, so all arrows should point towards the goal, right?

Comment: @Wolff only young ones when they become older its okay for them to be slightly see through.

Comment: I agree. It *seems* upside down.

Comment: @joojaa regarding your latest reply to Wolff, can you explain? As for the direction, it's to splitting the most ambitious goal into smaller steps. That's easier when you are building it

Comment: He's just responding to my joke about his autocorrect error in his initial comment. Sorry for polluting your question. About the direction. I think I understand your logic, but I'm mostly talking about the direction of the arrows themselves. The arrowhead should be in the other end as an action leads to a goal, not the other way around.

Comment: @Wolff yeah I want to understand the joke :D. As for the direction, if it's `Action → Sub-goal → Final goal`, then you are asking "what is the goal of what we are doing?" If it's `Final goal → Sub-goal → Action`, then you are asking "how do we achieve our goal?". I think generally, in a graph, the source node is fixed but the sink nodes are changeable. If it's the first route then it implies that you will not change your action, and you are seeking for a justification for it, which is not what you want

Comment: I understand. I just think I can't get over seeing the arrows as time indicators. The arrowheads could perhaps be omitted altogether. (Joojaa writes "foal" instead of "goal" - a young horse. "Equine" means horse.)

Comment: haha I see. @joojaa can you explain why you thing the goal is too opaque? Do you mean a lighter color will work?

Comment: What i mean is you can not design your item properly because you can not express what your goal with this solution tree is. (as in your goal with all of this is too opaque. Not goal item in your graph.) Once you understand of what your priorities are based on what you want to say then yopu know how to make the solution tree say that thing better. LIkewise you cant just automatically

Comment: @joojaa so are you saying that the goal of this question (how to design the graph better) is opaque, rather than the current color I use in the item that is coincidentally named "goal" is opaque?

Comment: Wel sort of the design goal is unclear. Believe it or not graphic design is not really about stylishness but the ultimate purpose of the task greatly affects the end results. Maybe you need a heat map. Maybe you need the critical path outlined, maybe there needs to be a node size hierarchy.... dunno not enough context to say.

Comment: @joojaa I see. Thanks to your suggestion, my approach is now to make all of them grey, and only color the ones that I'm working on. However, I still wonder why the original purpose of the question is *too* unclear to you. I agree that I didn't emphasize it enough, but I did say that I want to distinguish the nodes easier. Also, would focusing on functionality make this question a UX question rather than a graphic design one?

Comment: @Ooker it can be either or. Structuring information is graphic design just as much as ux design.

Answer (score 1):

Some observations.

You could potentially have an issue that a flow chart normally is read as cause-effect. In this case, the goal is the cause, but in reality, is the... goal, so the effect. See if you can reduce that using a horizontal diagram or something.

If you rely only on colors, especially green and red you are leaving out the interpretation for color blind people. Test your example in a website like this: [color-blindness-simulator](https://www.color-blindness.com/coblis-color-blindness-simulator/)

IMHO, the outline gives consistency, not hierarchy, so in my opinion, all slots should have one outline. Probably, on the most important step, you could add a second outline.

This leaves you the option to, besides using a color scheme, use additionally a different shape (as one shape you used). Probably the goals are rounded, and the other steps have hard corners. See if this helps: [flowchart+shape+conventions](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=flowchart%20shape%20conventions)

On the example, the important step "better goal" is buried between all the other steps. See if you can move the "better goal" to the column on the right side. This way you have some western flow of reading... left to right.

You can use happier colors. All of them have a black tint, which reduces contrast to the text. Try using pastel colors.

Comment: As for moving `Better goal` to the right, if it's a better goal of a goal level 3 or 4, it's still be in the middle of the graph anyway. Regarding changing the shapes, in my actual graph all the labels are sentence-long. I have tried putting it into flowchart boxes and Graphviz making them a lot of padding. I'll check that again though. If I use hard corner for a nose type, which one do you find it's suited best: better goal or supporting goal?